# "Please correct the error below" in the Django admin when using custom user models

Tags: django

I am working on a Django app and I followed exactly [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) to build a custom User.

Now when I try to create a new user from the admin panel, I get this error message
[image]

so not very useful. Also I have the same problem whether I use the "change" form or the "create" form.

However if I try to create a new user through the shell, like

```
MyUser.objects.create_user(email="test@gmail.com", password=None)
```

it works.

---

### Troubleshooting

Here is the model of the custom user:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    A base user on the platform. Users are uniquely identified by
    email addresses.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = "Email address",
        max_length   = 100,
        unique       = True
    )
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    is_admin   = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        '''Does the user have a specific permission?'''
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        '''Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?'''
        return True
```

- One explanation is that it has something to do with a field of `MyUser` that has `blank=False` but that is not displayed by my `ModelForm`. I double checked, and it's fine.
- Another explanation would be that the validation of the admin creation form has somehow inherited from the default `User` model of `django.contrib.auth` and it is trying to find a field from `User` that does not exist in `MyUser`. How can I check that?
- Any idea?

Comment: it is most likely failing a validation on a hidden fields. what do you mean by `I double checked, and it's fine` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks for your answers but my problem actually came from my `UserAdmin` override.

More specifically, `UserAdmin` uses `add_form` and `form` to refer to the creation and change forms respectively. As I named my variables `creation_form` and `change_form`, it did not override the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` forms and that's why some fields did not validate because my `ModelForm`s were not displaying those `User` fields.

Now I have renamed `creation_form` to `add_form` and `change_form` to `form` inside my custom `UserAdmin` and it works like a charm :-)

Comment: I have renamed add_form to creation_form and form to change_form and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem.  But it wasn't in the Admin form, it was at the admin list.  I was using list_editable fields.  When I would save changes, I would get the "Please correct the error below" message with nothing highlighted.

My error was that I had included the first field in the list_display as list_editable.  To correct it, I add 'id' to the front of the list_display fields.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Django shouldn't let you have all list_display as list_editable but then force one to be a non-editable link and throw an error when you try to save anything.

Comment: I think django should throw debug information error if no field is highlighted.

Answer (score 6):

### Problem

I had a similar problem.
But that's pretty easy to solve.

---

### How to solve it step by step?

First of all we need to talk about **overriding**, as you said before.
Django by default uses username field in models. And you need to change it like this in your **models.py**:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

If you still really want to override a lot of code, next: create managers. Something about this: [django managers](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)
In your custom manages class you need to override user creation (create_user method) and create_superuser method With this samples:

```
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a User with the given email and password.
    """
    log.debug(f'Creating user: {email}')
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('The email must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    log.info('Created user %s', repr(user))
```

Only after all this steps you can take care about overriding existing **forms**.
Django doc about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-admin-full-example
implementation:

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

```
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', )


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', )
```

This forms are used for user Creation in your admin and User changing.
And only now you can add code in your admin.py and change your UserAdmin like that:

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': ('is_admin',),
        }),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_admin', 'is_root', )}
         ),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

Be sure to add **add_fieldsets** and to override **ordering** by email.
In add_fieldsets you need to 2 type of passwords. If there be only 1 - error occures. From your screen by the way.

---

I hope this helps everyone who ever encounters this problem.

Comment: `add_fieldsets = ( ( None, { "classes": ("wide",),"fields": (..., "password1",  "password2",)}))`
was solve my issue.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't render {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}. Instead, I used {'fields': ('email', 'password')}

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can help, because password `CharField` in `AbstractBaseUser` has `blank` property set default to `False`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        passwd = [field for field in self._meta.fields if field.attname is 'password']
        if passwd:
            passwd[0].blank = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating from Django 1.6.7 to Django 3.2 and hit this fun error with no explanation.

My solution was changing this line in the code

```
readonly_fields = ("id", "amount")
```

to

```
readonly_fields = ("amount",)
```

Seems old version of Django just allowed the `id` there even though the `id` wasn't visible in the form (it was hidden, so it was in the html), but the newer Django displays an error with no message.

Here's the code context after the fix, was an admin stacked inline class

```
class BankInfo(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Statement
    form = StatementInlineForm
    fields = (
        "id",
        "amount",
        ...
    )
    readonly_fields = ["amount"]
    extra = 1
    raw_id_fields = ("balance",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I also stumbled upon this problem with the following appearing at the top of an admin form when trying to save an already existing record. No other errors were shown or given.

```
Please correct error below
```

After stripping my model down and checking over admin many times I stumbled into a field I had not updated in my Admin Form.   I had renamed title_long to title and not updated the adminForm. Correcting this allowed it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i mistakenly typed fieldsets instead of add_fieldsets in the accounts/admin.py

```html
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


#Import both the forms
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

#Import the model
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser

    list_display = [
        "email",
        "username",
        "name",
        "is_staff",
    ]

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ((None, {"fields": ("name",)}),)
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.**add_fieldsets** + ((None, {"fields": ("name",)}),)


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)

# Register your models here.
```

Changing it solved my problem. Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.